# I can't print data that I scrapped with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm doing a scraping course. I'm extracting data from a web using webdriver and selenium.
While it worked before, I can't print the info at all.

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
website = "https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/teamgoals/detailed"
path = r"H:/PROGRAMMING/Learning and Proyects/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= f"{path}")
driver.get(website)
all_matches_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@analytics-event="All matches"]')
all_matches_button.click() 
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("country"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Spain")
matches = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
for match in matches:
    match.txt
    print(match.txt)
```

At the end I receive this:

> "H:\PROGRAMMING\anaconda\envs\Learning and Proyects\python.exe" "H:/PROGRAMMING/Learning and Proyects/Test scrape yelp.py"
> Process finished with exit code 0

It is supposed to print the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see how this code could work ever. The only way this could work is to run it in debug mode step by step, but not in a normal run mode.
You are missing waits here.
These should preferably be Expected Conditions explicit waits.
Please try the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
website = "https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/teamgoals/detailed"
path = r"H:/PROGRAMMING/Learning and Proyects/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= f"{path}")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(website)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//label[@analytics-event="All matches"]'))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'country')))
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("country"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Spain")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//tr')))
time.sleep(0.5)
matches = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
for match in matches:
    print(match.text)
```

Comment: lol i was just following the step by step from the course, and it's funny cuz it worked before, now, the waits was something that i was actually questioning to myself, so ill try this and then i tell you how it went, thank you so much :)

Comment: So, i did as you said, i left some parts that were working before, now im actually getting and error, and i think it makes sense: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'txt'. Did you mean: 'text'?    Now, when i type match. i dont see the usual popup telling me ca i can pick txt from options, im searching about a fix, just wanted to update. :)

Comment: Sure, it should be `.text` I just copy-pasted your code :)